# Player Can't Move(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a "ground" plane with boxcollider and a capsule representing a player in a gamemanger class

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    double groundthickness = 0.1;
    /*GameObject != gameObject*/
    GameObject ground = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

    /*if you need add position, scale and color to the cube*/
    ground.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    ground.transform.localScale = new Vector3(100, (float)groundthickness, 100);
    ground.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
    BoxCollider boxCollider = ground.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

    GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);


    GameObject player = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
    player.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
    player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    player.AddComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    player.AddComponent<PlayerController>();

    UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent(player,       
    "Assets/Gamemanager.cs (30,9)", "Camera");

}
```

I then attached a playerController script to the capsule which is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            rb.velocity += Vector3.forward;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            rb.velocity += Vector3.down;
        }
}
```

I attached a rigidbody manually in game just to test but the capsule still wont move! Should be easy enough to do but cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Have you considered you may not be applying enough force?  Normally you don’t set velocity but apply force

Comment: If you created your player at runtime, how you attached manually the rigidbody component? If you have done it at runtime this is not working because PlayerController.Start is executed before that.

Comment: Cristiano is correct. You could create rigidbody in start()

Comment: you can test if @CristianoSchiaffella is correct by making rb public. It will probably be null.

Comment: thank you for the responses. it turned out i wasn't supposed to put a collider on the ground.

Comment: as implied here: https://www.makeuseof.com/player-movement-in-unity-explained/